# Which one is efficient : Java Request, JSR223 or BeanShell Sampler for my script

Tags: jmeter

I want to send a a byte array which is not possible with the inbuilt HTTP Sampler.

So went ahead with BeanShell sampler.

But i found some time lagging in response of BeanShell Sampler

In my code I am sending a hard-coded byte array to the web service endpoint.

[image]

Is there a better approach like Java Request or JSR223 whose execution time is lesser than that of beanshell sampler

Comment: Has anyone tried it and found any of them faster   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well-behaved [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language and [Compilation Cache feature](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) enabled will work faster and have lesser memory footprint than Beanshell. Remember not to reference JMeter Functions or Variables in form of `${var}` directly in Groovy script body.

[Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler will the fastest one, however it will be harder to make changes as you will have to recompile your code, put it to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter even for trivial change.

More information: [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)

---

Particularly in your case you can use [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) instead of scripting.

Comment: Hey Dmitiri, none of the images in your link are loading, which means all the crucial results data is missing

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to enable `Use multipart/form-data` in HTTP Request Sampler and then send your array as parameter.

You can store byte[] in variable using Beanshell:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[] {...};
vars.putObject("myByteArray", arr);
```

After that just refer to variable as usual ${myByteArray}.